# How to draw (scribble) a route over map and get all lat-longs on that route

Tags: ios, google-maps, geolocation, cllocationmanager, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to give my users ability to draw a route I will stop scroll when the user is drawing the route.

I want to be able to draw the route and get all the lat-long points on the route.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the CGPoint's of the route they've painted into CLLocationCoordinate2D's.